# Schedule Cron only the week

Tags: cron

I have this on my crontab

```
10 6 * * * java -jar /.../myproject.jar >> /../myjob.log 2>&1
```

I want run my app only the week (Monday to Friday)

This line is ok ? :

```
10 6 * * 1-5 java -jar /.../myproject.jar >> /../myjob.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a correct way to run the job on days 1 through 5 (Sunday being 0 (or 7)). Alternatively, you could explicitly list the days:

```
10 6 * * 1,2,3,4,5 java -jar /.../myproject.jar >> /../myjob.log 2>&1
```

You'll want to be careful about adding a "day of month" (field 3) restriction, apart from `*`; if both values are specified, then cron will run the job when *either* field matches.

Comment: +1 for pointing out day-of-week + day-of-month strange behavior (OR instead of AND)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks right.

```
10 6 * * 1-5 java -jar /.../myproject.jar >> /../myjob.log 2>&1
```

This would run the command at 06:10 (6.10am) every week day (Monday to Friday).